# Errno::ENOMEM when process shell out while using swap

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, memory

I have a ruby script that loads a lot of data in memory and then needs to shell out to perform a task on this data. But sometimes, the data is so big that the script is running in the swap, and in this case, shelling out gives me an `Errno::ENOMEM` error.

Here is the script to reproduce the problem:

```
def current_process_ram
  pid, size = `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)
  size / 1000
end

def display_current_process_ram
  "Current RAM: #{current_process_ram}"
end

puts display_current_process_ram

array = []
one_gig = 14_000_000
0.upto(one_gig * 2.5) do
  array << '12345'
end
sleep 2
`ls`

puts display_current_process_ram
```

## `htop` before running the script:

[image: before running script]

## `htop` when the script is running:

[image: while script is running]

## Resulting error:

```
deploy@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/statusmachine$ ruby test.rb
Current RAM: 7
test.rb:19:in ``': Cannot allocate memory - ls (Errno::ENOMEM)
        from test.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

It runs on an Ubuntu server "trusty tahr" VM.

## My question

Why do I get the `Errno::ENOMEM` error? I would expect the system call to work since I have enough swap to perform it.

---

Edit: If I change the script to only use 1 gig, it doesn't explode when shelling out.

Edit 2: When I shell out, there is still a lot of swap to perform the system call, so there shouldn't be an `Errno::ENOMEM` happening.

Edit 3: Clarified my question.

Comment: So, what is your question??

Comment: @maxd I updated the post to clarify my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I get the Errno::ENOMEM error?

Because Ruby can't allocate enough memory.

Ruby's memory management is difficult (IMHO) with regard to shelling out when you're using the typical Ruby, a.k.a. KRI, MRI, YARV.

Here's an article that may help you:

http://adamniedzielski.github.io/blog/2014/02/05/fighting-paperclip-errno-enomem-error/

The key idea in the article is: "To create the child process, free memory must be greater than the memory taken by the parent process."

The solution in the article is to switch to using the `posix-spawn` gem:

https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn

Comment: At least now I understand the behaviour. And I will try posix-spawn. Thanks a lot!